# The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject

Tags: flutter, frontend, backend

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a
RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically,
Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a _SingleChildViewport widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
Column ← Expanded ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#c46b1] ← Semantics ← Listener
← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#e1284] ←
Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Comment: can you post the specific code that cause the problem? in your build method

Answer (score 1):

There are may things to get this problem..

1. Under **ListView** don't use **Spacer Widget**
2. Don't use **Positioned** under **Row** or **Column**
3. **Expanded** can only use it must be a descendant of **Column** **Row** **Flex**

Comment: bro in that code i didn't used listview or positioned